# Sort by related model attributes in GridView Yii Framework 2.0

Tags: php, sorting, gridview, yii2

I have `Post` model and two related models, `User` and `Comments`.

Relation with `User` and `Comment` model defined in `Post` model:

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}

public function getUserName()
{
    return $this->user->name;
}

public function getComments(){
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::className(), ['comment_id' => 'id']);;
}

public function countCommentPoints() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::className(), ['comment_id' => 'id'])->sum('point');
}
```

My `PostSearch` model looks like following. I omitted the code andFilterWhere() because it is out of the scope:

```
class PostSearch extends Post {
    public $userName;

    public function rules()
    {
         return ['userName', 'safe'];
    }

    public function search($params) {
         $query = Post::find();
         $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
             'query' => $query,
         ]);

         $dataProvider->setSort([
             'attributes' => [
                  'userName' => [
                      'asc' => ['user.name' => SORT_ASC],
                      'desc' => ['user.name' => SORT_DESC],
                  ],
             ],
         ]);

         if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
             $query->joinWith(['user']);            
             return $dataProvider;
         }
    }

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

View code:

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'title',
        [
             'attribute' => 'userName',
             'value' => 'userName',
             'label' => 'User Name'
        ],
        [
             'attribute' => 'comment',
             'value' => function($model){
                  return $model->countCommentPoints();
             },
             'label' => 'Points',
        ],
     ],
]);
```

With all the code above I could sort the records by `id` and `title` and by `userName` which is an attribute of the related `User` model. But I could not sort by the column `Points` since it is not an attribute of the `Comment` model but a sum value returned from the `getLeadEarningPerWebmaster()` method. I have tried to read Yii 2.0 documentation here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html but the section **Sorting Data** is still under development. How can I make `GridView` sort by the `Points` column?

Comment: The sorting applies to all records, not just to current page. Maybe you are doing something wrong (for example applying additional filters in search model). Check again and add more info  or screenshots if problem will not be solved.

Comment: You are right. Sorting applies to all records, but I don't know how to make it apply to the joined model. I have edited my question and code. As shown in my code above, it does not sort by user.name. Do you know how?

Comment: I don't see any joins in your query.

Comment: Sorry I didn't add the Post model source code which has this relational method: public function getUser(){ return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']); }

Comment: I do not think you can do it with relations alone. You probably need to manually join with the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort GridView columns by related columns that are not necessarily inside the original ActiveRecord.

```
echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $model->joinWith([
            'comment' => function ($query) {
                    $query->select('SUM(point) AS sum')->from(['comment' => '{{%comment}}']);
            }
    ]),
    'sort' => [
            'attributes' => [
                    'comment.sum' => [
                            'asc' => ['comment.sum' => SORT_ASC],
                            'desc' => ['comment.sum' => SORT_DESC],
                    ]
            ],
            'sortParam' => 'post-sort',
            'defaultOrder' => ['comment.sum' => SORT_ASC]
    ],
]),
```

That should get you started.